# Integrate function of two variables with respect to one variable in R

Tags: r, integral

I'm trying to integrate a function of two variables with respect to just one of them in R, like \int_{0}^{1} f(x,y) dy. I have f(x,y) coded already but I'm struggling on how to compute the integral for all values of x (x is in (0,1) as well) in R. Any insight would be good.

Thank you

**Edit**

Here is my code (already with the suggested answer)

```
tdensity<-function(u,v,eta,rho){
s<-qt(u,df=eta)
r<-qt(v,df=eta)
numerador<-gamma((eta+2)/2)*gamma(eta/2)*((1+s^2/eta)*(1+r^2/eta))^((eta+1)/2)
denominador<-sqrt(1-rho^2)*(gamma((eta+1)/2))^2*(1+(s^2+r^2-2*rho*s*r)/(eta*(1-rho^2)))^((eta+2)/2)
return(numerador/denominador)
}

joedensity<-function(u,v,alpha){
w<-1-u
z<-1-v
dens<-(w^alpha+z^alpha-w*z^alpha)^(1/alpha-2)*w*z^(alpha-1)*(alpha-1+w^alpha+z^alpha-w*z^alpha)
return(dens)
}

pi<-function(u,v,theta) return((u*v)^theta)

cstarfun<-function(u,v,rho,theta,alpha,eta,K){
dens<-(1/K)*(pi(u,v,theta)*tdensity(u,v,eta,rho)+(1-pi(u,v,theta))*joedensity(u,v,alpha))
return(dens)
}

g<-Vectorize(cstarfun) # actually I don't know where to define the values for eta=4, rho=0.7, theta=2, alpha=3, K=2.5
w<-function(u) integrate(function(v) g, 0,1)$value
w<-Vectorize(w)
plot(w,from=0,to=1)
```

The only requirement for u and v are that they are in (0,1). Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it in two steps.  First define a function of `x` to be the integral at that scalar value, then use `Vectorize` to make the function work on a vector.  For example:

```r
f <- function(x, y) x^2 + y^2 + x*y

# We'll assume that `f` accepts vector inputs and produces a vector   
# output.  If not, run

#  f <- Vectorize(f)

# to put loops in place to accomplish that.

# Then define the integral:

fx <- function(x) integrate(function(y) f(x, y), 0, 1)$value

# This is *not* vectorized, but we can vectorize it:

fx <- Vectorize(fx)

# and plot the result:

plot(fx, from = 0, to = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

*Edited to add*:  After your edit to the original question, I can provide more detail on how to accomplish this.  My understanding is that the integrand is `cstarfun`, where you want to integrate out the `v` parameter.   There are two possibilities for how to define the `fx` function.

If you want the additional parameters `rho,theta,alpha,eta,K` to be arguments to the final function answer, you would define it as

```
fx <- function(u, rho,theta,alpha,eta,K)
        integrate(function(v) cstarfun(v, rho,theta,alpha,eta,K),
                  0, 1)$value
Vectorize(fx)
```

Then you would need to specify those 5 parameters each time you called it.

Alternatively, you could set those as global variables, and define `fx` with only `u` as a parameter, e.g.

```r
# This line is not necessary for your current definitions of the 
# functions, but doesn't hurt much.  It will just slow things down
# a bit.

cstarfun <- Vectorize(cstarfun, "v")

# Use your own choice of parameter values here!
# These ones lead to numerical issues
rho <- 0
theta <- 1
alpha <- 2
eta <- 3
K <- 4
fx <- function(u)
  integrate(function(v) 
              cstarfun(u, v, rho,theta,alpha,eta,K),
            0, 1)$value
fx <- Vectorize(fx)
```

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the answer. However, I still get an error... my function is given by 

fun<-function(u,v,eta,rho,alpha,theta,K){
  dens<-(1/K)*cstarfun(u,v,rho,theta,alpha,eta)
  return(dens)
} 

where cstarfun is another function in R. When I do the Vectorize, I get this error

Error in integrate(function(v) fun1, 0, 1) : 
  evaluation of function gave a result of wrong length

Comment: I'll have to ask for the standard thing: please post a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: My mistake, sorry. I edited the original post now